# Ability to CRUD Topic attribute in Google::Apis::ClassroomV1::CourseWork class?

Tags: ruby, rest, google-classroom

I was wondering if there is a way via the Ruby API doc to modify a Topic for the following class:
[Google::Apis::ClassroomV1::CourseWork](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/ClassroomV1/CourseWork)

Topics were introduced in August 2016 as far as I can tell as a way for teachers to organize their stream:
https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6149237?hl=en

Does anyone know of a way?  I'm okay with making a REST call as well if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JSON response https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork. 
It doesnt look like they have added the functionality to update a Topic through courses.CourseWork

```
JSON representation
{
  "courseId": string,
  "id": string,
  "title": string,
  "description": string,
  "materials": [
    {
      object(Material)
    }
  ],
  "state": enum(CourseWorkState),
  "alternateLink": string,
  "creationTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "dueDate": {
    object(Date)
  },
  "dueTime": {
    object(TimeOfDay)
  },
  "maxPoints": number,
  "workType": enum(CourseWorkType),
  "associatedWithDeveloper": boolean,
  "submissionModificationMode": enum(SubmissionModificationMode),

  // Union field details can be only one of the following:
  "assignment": {
    object(Assignment)
  },
  "multipleChoiceQuestion": {
    object(MultipleChoiceQuestion)
  },
  // End of list of possible types for union field details.
}
```